# c++ convert decimal into binary and stores in unsigned char

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

I need to be able to store a signed decimal value (no larger than -200 to +200) into an unsigned char[4].

At first I was thinking of using

```
union
{
 float f;
 unsigned char u[4];
}
```

as float is also 4bytes.

but the binary value it generates doesnt match its value (i.e 7 doesnt shows 0111).  << I was so wrong on hoping that floating point would work.

I'm thinking of using double and only store the LSB 4 bytes into the unsigned char by using bitwise operations.

Is there any "best solution" out there for my problem? Please provide a hint somewhere so that I can look into it! thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that `7` in a `float` representation should yield `0111` actually?

Comment: why do you need to store it in an `unsigned char[4]` ? Some background info here could be useful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Is this an integer or floating point number you wish to store?  If it's an integer, use an integer type that is 4 bytes on your machine.  If floating point, then be aware that floating point uses an obscure binary representation (see link posted above).  Also beware of endianness issues even if you're storing integers.

Comment: I need to store it into unsigned char[4] to be send out to another program and to "save bytes" as the range is -200 ~ +200, 4 bytes is more than enough (restriction due to requirement), what the receiving program does with the value is none of my concern but I got to stick by the requirements given :(

I was hoping for 7 to be 0111 .n yes it doesnt turns out as i hoped it would be for float.. 


@SimonB I need to be able to send e.g. -0.125 in binary stored in the unsigned char and be able to read it back as -0.125 at the receiving end

Comment: well in actual fact, I had to convert the value to binary in two's complement form and stores it into the unsigned char, but I wanted to test it out myself first with the normal binary representation before venturing into two's complement :)

Comment: Just use a `short`! Or beter, `int16` if you have it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to [...] store a signed decimal value (no larger than -200 to
>   +200) into an unsigned char[4].

In the embedded world, the following function "int16ToStr()" works fine, but in this context is only meant to be illustrative of the technique.  (Note that I have used bitset only for the convenience of displaying in binary, otherwise not needed).

This code extracts the 8 bit bytes (from value) and writes them into the chars in the corresponding order.

If you need the other order, use htonl or ntohl to reverse the parameter 'value' in the beginning of int16ToStr().

If every unsigned char must be a printable char, then you need to clarify that idea in your problem description.

Here, the raw 16 bit (because of small range) decimal integer is simply transferred to raw unsigned chars.

Note that the first two bytes of the "unsigned char str[4]" are always either 0x00 or 0xff because the decimal range only needs two bytes == two chars.

```
#include  <bitset>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

// transfers 16 bit content of value to 4 chars
void int16ToStr(int16_t       value,
                unsigned char str[4])
{
   std::cout << "\n  value: " << std::dec << value << "  " << std::endl;
   std::bitset<16> bset(value);
   std::cout << " bitset: " << bset << std::endl;

   // leastSignificant Nibble - last to print
   str[3] = static_cast<unsigned char>(( value >>  0) & 0xff); // lsNibl 
   str[2] = static_cast<unsigned char>(( value >>  8) & 0xff); 
   str[1] = static_cast<unsigned char>(( value >> 16) & 0xff); 
   str[0] = static_cast<unsigned char>(( value >> 24) & 0xff); // msNibl 
   // mostSignificant Nibbl - 1st

   std::cout << "  uchar: ";
   for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) std::cout  << std::setfill ('0') 
                                      << std::hex  << std::setw(2) 
                                      << static_cast<int>(str[i]) << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

// test 244 invoked from main
int t244(void)
{
   for (int16_t val0 = -200; val0 <= -199; ++val0)
   {
      unsigned char    str0[4];
      int16ToStr(val0, str0);
   }

   for (int16_t val1 = -2; val1 <= 2; ++val1)
   {
      unsigned char str1[4] ;
      int16ToStr(val1, str1);
   }

   for (int16_t val2 = 199; val2 <= 200; ++val2)
   {
      unsigned char str2[4] ;
      int16ToStr(val2, str2);
   }

   return (0);
}
```

---

output:

```
  value: -200  
 bitset: 1111111100111000
  uchar: ff ff ff 38 

  value: -199  
 bitset: 1111111100111001
  uchar: ff ff ff 39 

  value: -2  
 bitset: 1111111111111110
  uchar: ff ff ff fe 

  value: -1  
 bitset: 1111111111111111
  uchar: ff ff ff ff 

  value: 0  
 bitset: 0000000000000000
  uchar: 00 00 00 00 

  value: 1  
 bitset: 0000000000000001
  uchar: 00 00 00 01 

  value: 2  
 bitset: 0000000000000010
  uchar: 00 00 00 02 

  value: 199  
 bitset: 0000000011000111
  uchar: 00 00 00 c7 

  value: 200  
 bitset: 0000000011001000
  uchar: 00 00 00 c8
```

---

-200 to +200 is 400, which is bigger than a single char (1 byte => 256), but will fit into two chars (2 bytes == 16 bits).  You specifically indicated char[4], which is bigger than necessary.

Perhaps you intended some other constraints?

Comment: I apologise as I think I created some misunderstanding. The requirement should be -200.0 to +200.0 up to 2 precision decimal placing i.e the value to be converted to binary could be 150.59 , or -20.48 etc.

hence I think I should just multiply the value by 100 first before doing what you have suggested..yea It seems that even after scaling the value up, 2^16 is still enough. I shall suggest to reduce the size needed for this parameter. 

thanks !

Comment: @user1693492 - I seldom have use for float or double, though both are supported on most hardware these days.  However, for your effort you need to look into the memory layout of a float (or double) ... I seem to remember mantissa, exponent, and not simple layout.  Sizeof(float) is 4 bytes, Sizeof(double) is 8 bytes.  But shift and mask work on int.  Be sure to research the layout of the bits in float (or double).  The layout may affect how to use a mask and shift technique, but there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment indicates the intent is to send this value to another program.

To do so, first turn the value into a positive value (by adding 200 eg.), then use [`htons`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) (or [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) if necessary) to reorder the bytes in network byte order :

```
int32_t input = /*your value between -200 and 200 */;
uint16_t value = htons((uint16_t) (input + 200));
```

this value can then be sent to the other program, eg. :

```
write(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
```

The receiver would then do the opposite with the received value by using [`ntohs`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) (resp. [`ntohl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl)) :

```
uint16_t value = 0;
read(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
int32_t output = ((int32_t) ntohs(value)) - 200;
```

and `output` would have the same value as `input`.